# Add Time To A Date Only Inside Preset Hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do something as follows:

> Date & Time: 27/09/2019 13:28
>
> Working Day: Monday - Friday 8am - 5:30PM (08:00 -> 17:30) (NetworkDays)
>
> Duration: 9.5hrs (09:30 hrs)
>
> Outcome: 30/09/2019 13:28

Logic behind this is

> Date & Time + Duration (Only inside the "Working Day") = Outcome

Working Days should only be from Monday - Friday 8am - 5:30pm and excludes weekends. I believe NetworkDays handles this?

If the Date & Time + Duration carries across weekend, then the time carries across to the following Monday.

Is there anything that can handle something like this?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can duration be more than 9.5 hours, possibly requiring to go over more than 2 days?

Comment: It can yes. It can be in excess of some 200 hours for instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If A1 contains the Date/Time and A2 contains the Duration, then:

`=WORKDAY(A1,INT((A1-INT(A1)-8/24+A2/24)/9.5*24))+8/24+MOD(A1-INT(A1)-8/24+A2/24,9.5/24)`

Comment: Its almost there, Duration is formatted as a hh:mm:ss however. For instance 09:30:00 is 9hrs, 30 mins, 0 sec. Seems as though this is reading the "mm" field and working out from that without accounting for hours. Any ideas?

Comment: `=WORKDAY(B4,INT((B4-INT(B4)-8/24+(D4*24)/24)/9.5*24))+8/24+MOD(B4-INT(B4)-8/24+(D4*24),9.5/24)` Used this alteration to handle the hh:mm:ss formatting and now works flawlessly. Thank you @Michael